# Avoid overriding variable names

Tags: clojure

On a particular namespace I am working on I am beginning to run out of function names. Is there a way to get a warning like the one I get if I override a symbol from another namespace if I reuse a symbol which is already bound to a function in the same namespace?

Comment: you might want to tag this with the language/env you are developing in or add it to the description  . NM you just did.

Comment: What event occurs that makes you know you are running out of function names? I've been learning Clojure since this past May, so I've never heard of this happening.

Comment: Should some of the namespace be separated out into one or more other namespaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is enough of a problem that you'd be willing to replace a (set of) core macro(s), you could try this approach:

```
(ns huge.core
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [defn]))

(defmacro defn [name & defn-tail]
  (assert (nil? (resolve name))
          (str "Attempting to redefine already defined Var "
               "#'" (.name *ns*) "/" name))
  `(clojure.core/defn ~name ~@defn-tail))
```

Then any attempt to redefine an existing Var with `defn` will fail:

```
user=> (defn foo [] :foo)
#'user/foo
user=> (defn foo [] :bar)
AssertionError Assert failed: Attempting to redefine already defined Var #'user/foo
(nil? (resolve name))  user/defn (NO_SOURCE_FILE:2)
```

You could similarly replace `defmacro`; in that case you would have to call `clojure.core/defmacro` when defining your own variant.

Plain, unadorned `def` is a special form and receives magic treatment from the compiler, so you could still overwrite existing Vars with it. If you would like to guard against name clashes on that flank too, you could switch to something like `defvar` (used to be available in `clojure.contrib.def`) with a similar custom assert.

Comment: Just to clarify, it is possible to register a macro called `def`, but the compiler will ignore it. Also, if the "running out of names" problem is limited to just the one namespace, I'd put the macros on top of it; otherwise it would be more convenient to put them in their own namespace and `:use` it wherever necessary. All client namespaces would still need to use the `:refer-clojure` clause.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't quite an answer to your question but may help avoid the issue depending on how the functions in your namespace are being used. You could make them into local functions using **letfn**, allowing you to reuse names for functions that are only used within the context of another function.

```
(defn main-fn [x]
  (letfn [(secondary-fn [x] (* x x))
          (another-fn [x] (secondary-fn (inc x)))]
    (/ (another-fn x) 4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you restrict yourself to single-character function names, you are in no danger of running out, as there are (about) 64 thousand Unicode characters, any one of which is a valid function name.

Given that you can in fact have names that are ten thousand characters long, you are on even safer ground.

Comment: Not every valid symbol (whether or not Clojure supports reading a symbol with arbitrary Unicode characters) is a useful identifier.  For example aolskSAdjfjlDFksdioeFwmvkldjskSFODIJFLKSMEOVISLEKasdeDFeasD should be a perfectly valid symbol, but you should never actually use that for as an identifier in a real program with English names.